# Al redireccionar con .httaccess de www a no www, añade doble slash al final de la url principal

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

¡Hola!

A ver si me podéis echar una mano :)

Estoy intentando modificar el httaccess de mí blog para que cuando intenten acceder por www redireccione a no www y el caso es que lo consigo, pero cuando se redirige a la página de inicio me añade un doble slash al final, ej: https://loquesea.com//

El caso es que con las demás urls no me pasa y es algo que me está desesperando un poco.

Esta es la regla que estoy usando:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^/]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Con la expresión regular intento sacar solo la parte de loquesea.com y he probado haciéndola con código y funciona perfectamente así que no se porque puede estar pasando.

La web está hecha con Django, no se si puede estar influyendo en algo.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Intenta con lo indicado aquí https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/, referido en https://stackoverflow.com/a/2475982/5675636

Comment: Hola Carmen, con ese ejemplo me ha funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!, con la solución que pasó Carmen en los comentarios lo pude solucionar, la explicación de como resolverlo está en este link: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/